# Firebase 5 Angular 5 AngularFireList.snapshotChanges() error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, angularfire2

When I try to subscribe an AngularFireList in Angular 5/Firebase5 application giving the following error.

```
zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (changes.js:7)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:91)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:56)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (delay.js:91)
```

My Service and Controller class content as follows,

1) Service named 'FirebaseService'

```
customers: AngularFireList<any>;
getCustomers(){
    this.customers = this.fire.list('users');
    return this.customers;
  }
```

2) Controller

```
constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService) { }

serviceProviders: ServiceProvider[];
var x = this.firebase.getServiceProviders();
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
      this.serviceProviders = [];      
      item.forEach(element => {
        var y = element.payload.toJSON();
        y["$key"] = element.key;
        this.serviceProviders.push(y as ServiceProvider);
      });
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide more context so we can help you out;

code where you try to subscribe, firebase service if you have any, structure of the list you are trying to retrieve...

Comment: Hi Javier,

     I have added the code where I try to subscribe and the service trying to retrieve list of data. Hope that would be help to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recent releases of AngularFire require rxjs 6. Please upgrade rxjs and include `rxjs-compat` if you have dependencies that haven't upgraded.

Comment: You might want to double check your work. That is 100% the cause and fix. I'm the maintainer of AngularFire btw ;)

Comment: WOW, I was looking for the entire web for this solution

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem while using AngularFireList.valueChanges()
there is an npm warning when you install recent release of AngularFire (5.0.0-rc.10)

> npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed

so I have installed that dependency

`npm install rxjs@^6.0.0 --save` in my project

It is also necessary to install the following dependency.

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

and the problem is solved